# Probably a very simply answerable query about throwing an exception

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, illegalargumentexception

This should be easily and quickly answerable. It is about throwing exceptions, and I have very little understanding of that topic (because I am a novice).

The code below represents of the most important methods from my simple 'maze game' program. In this method, I am (obviously) enumerating the possible user keyboard commands and giving the instructions for their execution by calling other sub-methods. Evidently, I want all keyboard inputs that aren't "help", "status" ... "down" to result in the error message at the bottom of the method.

I know that what I've got here is dumb and makes no sense, but that's because I literally have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to throwing exceptions, and I am too lazy to do any serious reading. So I would love if someone could just tell me how to write what I want to write here.

```
public static void performAction(String action) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
      printHelp(); }
    else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("status")) {
      printStatus(); }
    else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("board")) {
      printBoard(); }
    else if (((action.charAt(0) == 'S') || (action.charAt(0) == 's')) && ((action.charAt(1) == 'a') || (action.charAt(1) == 'A')) && ((action.charAt(2) == 'v') ||  (action.charAt(2) == 'V')) &&
    ((action.charAt(3) == 'e') || (action.charAt(3) == 'E')) && (action.charAt(4) == ' ')) {
      String [] parts = action.split(" ");
      String saveCommand = parts[0];
      String fileName = parts[1];
        try { saveGame(fileName); }
        catch(IOException e) {
          System.err.printf("Error: Could not save the current game configuration to \'%s\'.", fileName);
          return; } }
    else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("left")) {
      int a = getCurrentXPosition();
      int b = getCurrentYPosition();
      moveTo((a - 1), b); }
    else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("right")) {
      int a = getCurrentXPosition();
      int b = getCurrentYPosition();
      moveTo((a + 1), b); }
    else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("up")) {
      int a = getCurrentXPosition();
      int b = getCurrentYPosition();
      moveTo(a, (b - 1)); }
    else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("down")) {
      int a = getCurrentXPosition();
      int b = getCurrentYPosition();
      moveTo(a, (b + 1)); }
    else {
      try {}
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      System.err.printf("Error: Could not find command \'%s\'.\nTo find the list of valid commands, please type 'help'. \n", action); }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `else { throw new IllegalArgumentException(yourMessage)}`

Comment: How is this different to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513726/how-to-limit-the-string-arguments-that-a-method-can-use-to-a-fixed-list

Comment: If you just want to print the error message, you don't need to throw any exception. Just print the error message in the `else` block.

Comment: "I am too lazy to do any serious reading" - how will you be able to learn anything then? Of course we could tell you how to use exceptions here but what would you learn from it? As you said you "have very little understanding of that topic" and that's probably the main problem: you need to understand that topic and that's best done by doing some reading and experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

else {
  System.err.printf("Error: Could not find command \'%s\'.\nTo find the list of valid commands, please type 'help'. \n", action);

throw IllegalArgumentException ;
    }
This will log the message and then exit the method by throwing IllegalArgumentException  exception